# Show a function is not a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by failing the triangle inequality

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

I'm trying to show the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(v) = (\sqrt{|v_1|} + \sqrt{|v_2|}$ is not a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by showing the triangle inequality doesn't hold. That is, I want to show $\Vert u + v \Vert > \Vert u \Vert + \Vert v \Vert$.

I believe I have correctly simplified the problem to a comparison between $\sqrt{|u_1| + |v_1|}\sqrt{|u_2| + |v_2|}$ on the LHS and $\sqrt{|u_1||u_2|} + \sqrt{|v_1||v_2|}$ on the RHS. I don't see how I can say with certainty that $\sqrt{|u_1| + |v_1|}\sqrt{|u_2| + |v_2|} > \sqrt{|u_1||u_2|} + \sqrt{|v_1||v_2|}$.

Am I missing some operation on square roots I can do or some other simplification or maybe a substitution? Perhaps I'm barking up the right tree altogether and should show $\Vert\alpha v\Vert \neq |\alpha|\Vert v\Vert$ instead?

Comment: You need to show $\|u+v\|>\|u\|+\|v\|$ **sometimes**, not always.  So just give one example of $u,v$ where this is true.  By playing around a bit with random numbers this should not take long.

Comment: @David of course, I see that now. Thanks